# Property '...' does not exist on type '{...}|{...}'

Tags: typescript

I have TypeScript function that based on input value returns one of two different objects:

```
function myfunc(isError:boolean): {response:string}|{error:string} {
  if(isError) return {error:''}
  return {response:''}
}
```

And then I try to use it and get property of returned object I get TypeScript error:

```
const answer = myfunc(true);
if(answer.error) {...}
else return answer.response;
```

> Property 'error' does not exist on type '{response:string}|{error:string}'

I know that I can check for property in object, but i don't want to do this for each property.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types and https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types

Comment: What TypeScript version are you using? With 3.3.3 and later the return type is inferred as  `{error: string; response?: undefined;} | {response: string; error?: undefined;}` and your code [works fine](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.5.1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ6kgChgZwKIBOBcBAXAEZxwA2ApgIZgCUiA3gFCKIzDb5EkWBWlBAEkrWgLIByGQF9OiYaPFthOAA4IctUnMWL2EHVESMcAdymIAvCnTgImKARC0mAbnY9MF6wQAdFLEBCysirTUuuZgVlKBGtpxtJ5AA).

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the type `{response:string}|{error:string}` doesn't guarantee that the error exists, you can either create an interface with optional properties like this:

```
interface answer {
    error?: string;
    response?: string;
}
```

and then type your function accordingly.

If you don't want this, you can typecast your object but this may not be that beautiful to write:

```
if((<{error: string}>answer).error) {...}
else return (<{error: response}>answer).response;
```

EDIT: As the comments mentioned, your code works perfectly fine in newer TypeScript versions, you should consider updating it

Answer (score 0):

I found solution that suits me.
I've create two interfaces and added Partial for them:

```
interface Response {response:string}
interface ErrMsg {error:string}
function myfunc(isError:boolean): Partial<Response&ErrMsg> {
  if(isError) return {error:''}
  return {response:''}
}
```